# How do I save the predictions obtained from the gcloud ml engine?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm using the windows powershell and using gcloud commands to request predictions from a python tensorflow savedmodel on gcloud ml engine. The output of the ml model prediction is actually an image and I want to save that image. I couldn't find a way to do this via the gcloud commands and was wondering if it was possible to do so.

For the record, the prediction does work because the predict command returns a large amount of data, presumably the output image.

Answer (score 1):

The method to save the response is:

gcloud ml-engine predict --model model_name --json-instances ./data/data.json **>>preds.json**

Adding >>preds.json to the end of that command saves the response to a json file.

Comment: By using two >> you will append to the file. Use a single > if you want to overwrite existing contents. Also, consider using the client API in the language of your choice if you are going to post-process the results (e.g., base64 decode the image).